# Angular 2 Server Express ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: node.js, angular, express, npm, server

I created a website using Angular2 for the frontend and Node/Express for the backend.  The frontend runs through port 4200 (npm run build in order to run it) and the backend through port 4201 (npm start).

I have a view to manage user connection (login/password) which works perfectly on localhost. Basically, I have a service which will be called on form submit to get the specified user. The problem is that when I try to the same thing on my own server, I get this error :

OPTIONS http://[HostIP]:4201/auth/login

> net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

My server is on 1&1 cloud, on a debian7 environnement. Firewalls seems clear and the port seems opened.

Do you have any idea of what's happening ? Is the issue coming from my code or from the server ?

Server.js :

```
const express = require('express');
const app= express();
const bodyParser= require('body-parser');

let data = require('./dataPics');

const fakeUser = {dataFakeUser};
const secret = 'mySecret';
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'content-type');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
  next();
});

const auth = express.Router();

auth.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  if(req.body){
    const login = req.body.login.toLocaleLowerCase();
    const password = req.body.password.toLocaleLowerCase();
    if(login === fakeUser.login && password === fakeUser.password){
      delete req.body.password;
      //res.json({ success: true, data: req.body});
      const token = jwt.sign({iss: 'http://localhost:4201', role: 'admin', user: req.body.login}, secret);
      res.json({ success: true, token: token});
    }
    else{
      res.json({ success: false, message: 'Identification Incorrecte'});
    }
  }
  else{
    res.json({ success: false, message: 'Merci de vous identifier'});
  }
});

app.use('/auth', auth);

const port = 4201;

app.listen(port, '[HostIP]', () => {
  console.log(`listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Service.ts :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import * as jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
// BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:4201/auth';
  BASE_URL = 'http://[HostIP]:4201/auth';

  constructor(private _http: Http) { }

  login(formData){
    return this._http.post(`${this.BASE_URL}/login`, formData)
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

  userIsLoggedIn(){
    return localStorage.getItem('jjw-data');
  }

  logOut(){
    localStorage.removeItem('jjw-data');
  }

  decodeToken(token){
    return jwtDecode(token);
  }

}
```

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

localhost is a special hostname whch will run only if open the url from the same machine web app hosted on you could try to change http://localhost:4201 with the public ip of the machine you hosted node app in 
http://[publicIp]:4201

```
if(req.body){
        const login = req.body.login.toLocaleLowerCase();
        const password = req.body.password.toLocaleLowerCase();
        if(login === fakeUser.login && password === fakeUser.password){
          delete req.body.password;
          //res.json({ success: true, data: req.body});
          const token = jwt.sign({iss: 'http://localhost:4201', role: 'admin', user: req.body.login}, secret);
          res.json({ success: true, token: token});
        }
```

If that solution doesn't work for you, you could try to run

> netstat -antu

In order to know if the port is in use by different application.

Comment: Thanks but it's doesn't work.   When I try `netstat -antu` there is not my port 4201

Comment: Does npm start gives you that error? When does this error exactly appears to you?

Comment: I think it's a backend issue, I ran into the same problem and I recognized that this error happened when I got an error from my backend, So Check your backend log file, I think you will find an error.

Comment: This error appears when I try to log me. I think the problem is when my app try to call my Express Server.